# location manager stuck at .notDetermined status even after calling requestAuthorizationWhenInUse()

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I am trying to build my first application in Swift using
SwiftUI and CoreLocation. This is my LocationManager observable class:

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation
import SwiftUI

@Observable class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let manager: CLLocationManager
    
    var lastLocation: CLLocation? {
        manager.location
    }
    
    override init() {
        manager = CLLocationManager()
        super.init()
        
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }
}

extension LocationManager {
    
    private func redirectToSettings() {
        if let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
    }
    
    func requestWhenInUseAuthorization() {
        return manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    
    private func handleAuthorizationStatusChange(_ status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            print("not determined")
            requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("yes")
            manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            return manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .authorizedAlways:
            return manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .denied, .restricted:
            return redirectToSettings()
        @unknown default:
            print("Unknown authorization status")
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("\(error)")
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        handleAuthorizationStatusChange(status)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print(locations)
    }
}
```

and this is the view code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    @Environment(LocationManager.self) var locationManager
    
    var body: some View {
        if let clLocation = locationManager.lastLocation {
            Text(clLocation.description)
        } else {
            Text("No location")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    FirstView()
}
```

and this is the ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            FirstView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Explore", systemImage: "globe")
                }
            SecondView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tortoise", systemImage: "tortoise")
                }
            ThirdView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Tortoise", systemImage: "tortoise")
                }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

The problem is: when the authorization callback gets called, the status value is .notDetermined, so I call request when in use to prompt the user to change the authorization status. The function gets called but the status does not change (the user is not prompted) therefore the callback isn't called a second time. In the privacy section of the settings the location services are enabled. What could be the problem?

Comment: `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` does not return any value and is _asynchronous_.

Comment: Where do you put `LocationManager` into the environment?  Also `case .denied, .restricted: return redirectToSettings()` isn't a good idea - It will launch the user into settings without providing them any details why - You should put the settings launch behind a button.  Also, if access is `.restricted` then they can't fix that in settings. Location is [disabled by something like parental controls or MDM](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clauthorizationstatus/restricted)

Comment: Finally, having `lastLocation` as a computed variable won't work well with SwiftUI - Computed variables can't trigger view updates.

Comment: @explosivemango do you have values for both `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` and  `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` keys in your `Info.plist` file?   `<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key> <string>Allow locations</string>`
`<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key> <string>Allow locations</string>`

Comment: Just to eliminate the obvious, youve added the pemrission string to your info.plist file right?